# Missing MediaType when using useReturnTypeSchema=true in Springdoc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I'm using `Spring` to write some web service, using `springdoc` to create nice Swagger endpoint documentation.

My controller endpoint method has this:

```
responses = {
    @ApiResponse(
        responseCode = "200",
        description = "Found",
        useReturnTypeSchema = true // <- THIS DOES NOT DEFINE A MEDIA TYPE
    ),
    <...>
```

This makes it so easy to auto-detect the return type (even for generic types) and define a schema for it. But there is no media-type definition when using this option. I would expect `application/json`.

I tried to search the docs but could not find anything about it.

**Does anyone know, how to get the mediaType AND use the auto schema detection?**

[image: SwaggerUI entry without media type]

When using normal

```
@Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class))}
```

I get my correct media type:

[image: SwaggerUI entry with correct media type]

Environment Info:

- Spring Boot: `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.1'`
- Swagger docs: `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2`
- Java: `17.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{assetId}/shifts", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

By defining a `produces` in the mapping, this media type is used also in the swagger docs.

[image: SwaggerUI with correct media type]

Answer (score 1):

You can change a default produces media type, which is set to `/`, by adding a property to the `application.properties`:

```
springdoc.default-produces-media-type=application/json
```

This eliminates the need to define the `produces` parameter in each mapping.

For reference: [springdoc.org](https://springdoc.org/core-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can mention both consumes and produces at the global level in the `application.properties` file

```
springdoc:
  default-consumes-media-type: application/json
  default-produces-media-type: application/json
```